# How to avoid Ajax in wordpress theme in making mulitple request?

Tags: theme-development, ajax

here is my function that make request, When ever page loads this scripts makes multiple request in front end making web site load very slow.

```
 function enqueue_scripts_styles_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
    // get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js'; // Inside a parent theme
    // get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js'; // Inside a child theme
    // plugins_url( '/js/script.js', __FILE__ ); // Inside a plugin
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_styles_init');

function ajax_action_stuff() {
    $post_id = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['whatever'])); // getting variables from ajax post

//$post_id = array('apis','all','cro');
  // doing ajax stuff
 foreach($post_id as $value)
 {
  $idObj = get_category_by_slug($value); 
  $id[] = $idObj->term_id;
 }

 if(empty($id))
    {
        echo "empty";
    } 
    else
    {
        $args = array (
              'category__in' => $id,
              'posts_per_page' => 10,
              'order' => 'DESC'

          );

          $posts = get_posts( $args );

          ob_start ();
          foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
          setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

          <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> <?php post_class(); ?>">
              <h2 class="posttitle">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
              </h2>
              <p><?php
              $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
              $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['link_url'];
              if(!empty($my_custom_field)) 
              {
                echo '<a href="'.$my_custom_field[0].'" title="">'.$my_custom_field[0].'</a>';
              }
              ?></p>
              <div id="post_content_seo">
              <?php echo $post->post_content; ?>
              <?php $t = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                echo "<br/><strong>Tags:</strong>";
                foreach($t as $tag)
                {
                  ?>
                   <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?>,</a>
                  <?php
                }
      ?>
              </div>
         </div>

         <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
          $response = ob_get_contents();
         ob_end_clean();
         echo $response;
    }

   die(1); 
     // stop executing script
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' ); // ajax for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_stuff' ); // ajax for not logged in users
```

Here is the image of how page loads when page is opened. How do I avoid this type of error?

[image]

Comment: You are doing a `get_post()` (DB) request on all the post IDs that you fetched. What's the problem you are facing? Rewrite it to do less requests...

Comment: what triggers the ajax request? you didn't show us the javascript which initiates these requests.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, you were, almost right. I was sending request on all the post IDS